# Automapper ProjectTo DefaultIfEmpty Configuration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, automapper-8

AutoMapper v 8.1.1 / EF6

In this example, where `Owner.CarId = null`, `OwnerDto.Car` is also `null`. So if the default behavior is `null` on a nested property, is there a way to handle the equivalent of `.DefaultIfEmpty(new CarDto())` in `ProjectTo`?

In using a `ProjectTo` map to convert an optional one-to-one database relationship, if the `Owner.CarId is NULL`, the `CarDto` property is `null`. I thought the default behavior (based on [how null collections are handled](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections) as I didn't see any mention of how nulls would be evaluated in [Nested Mappings](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html)) was to return a new `CarDto` object...and then from there, wasn't sure if the properties of that new `CarDto` object would be their [natural default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) (i.e. `int = 0`) or they'd be `null`.

Source Classes

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Destination Classes

```
public class CarDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class OwnerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CarDto Car { get; set; }
    public int? CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Configuration

```
new MapperConfiguration(settings =>
{
    settings.CreateMap<Owner, OwnerDto>()
    settings.CreateMap<Car, CarDto>();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `.ForMember(destination => destination.Car, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(new CarDto())));` on `settings.CreateMap<Owner, OwnerDto>()`?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I do not want `null`, I'm looking for a new instance of `CarDto` to be created with all properties having their native c# default values.

Comment: @Fildor I did, but it did not work either. Note these property names are not the same so I still need to use a `option.MapFrom()` So wasn't sure how to also do a `option.NullSubstitute()` on the same destination property. I just put a second .ForMember line for the same Dest property. Is that right? How do you apply these 2 destination options together?

Comment: If you already have a `MapFrom`, just write the null check there.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can you be more specifi? This does not work: 
`option.MapFrom(c => c.Car).NullSubstitute(new Car())`. 
Making 2 separate ForMember() lines does, i.e. 
`.ForMember(dest => dest.Car, option => option.MapFrom(c => c.Car))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Car, option => option.NullSubstitute(new Car()))`